# How to use java.awt.image package in android app

Tags: android, image

I have to use  `java.awt.image` package for `BufferedImage` class in my android app, but I am not able to do this and does anyone knows that how to do this in Android or what's the equivalent class of `java.awt.Image` in Android?

Answer (score 8):

**android.graphics.Bitmap.** is equivalent to BufferedImage.

Comment: @user286919 does my answer address your issue.